# make NAMESPACE declaration conditional?

Tags: php, namespaces

I include `myfile.php` file 2 times.. I want to know if there is way to put in the start of `myfile.php` something like this:

```
if($authorized){
    Namespace MyProject;
}

function ABC(){}
function EFG(){}
```

(I do this to avoid function-redefine errors. Please dont ask me why I do such thing.. I know there are `if function_exists` and etc.. but I need answers to what I ask).

**update:**
I do this, because I need to define `function XYZ()` and using that before other framework is loaded (which newly defines globally `function XYZ()`).  So I want to use that function (with different functionality) before framework loads, and after framework loads, it should behave as framework decides.

Comment: I'm pretty sure you can't do that.

Comment: What *exactly* are you trying to do here?  It sounds like you are trying to solve the wrong problem.

Comment: function redefine error is exactly why namespace has been implented... I don't think you fully understand what you're trying to achieve here

Comment: i've updated question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Is there a way to make namespace's conditional?

Although this is impossible directly, I could suggest using the `define()` method to create this yourself. Where the file requiring the class needs to have a allowed definition to access the file.

```
define('IN_NAMESPACE', 0);

if(defined('IN_NAMESPACE')) {
    // authorized
}
```

But if you're worrying about a class name being repeated, namespaces are for the declaration of environments so you do not get duplicates, for example:

```
namespace Environments\One;
class Example { }

namespace Environments\Two;
Class Example { }

use Environments\One\Example as ExampleOne;
use Environments\Two\Example as ExampleTwo;

$e_o = new ExampleOne();
$e_t = new ExampleTwo();
```

Or simply, directly say you will use this environment like so:

```
$e_o = new Environments\One\Example();
$e_t = new Environments\Two\Example();
```

But again, this issue is not canonical to PHP. Use MVC methodologies to over-come these issues and Singleton/Dependency Injection design patterns.